# Can span of two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ generate whole $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose I have two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and I linearly combine them. Can and will they generate whole $2\text D$ plane?
My teacher did an example and showed that such vectors can't span $\mathbb{R}^2$ because they will be a $2\text D$ plane (a sheet) in $3\text D$ ($\mathbb{R}^3$).
Kindly answer with example.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The vectors $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ span a two-dimensional subspace (the plane with equation $z=0.)$  I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, but this example should answer your question.

Comment: Maybe your teacher is distinguishing between $\mathbb R^2$ and $\{(x,y,0)\}\subset \mathbb R$?

Comment: "such vectors can't span $\mathbb{R}^2$ because they will be a 2D plane (a sheet) in 3D ($\mathbb{R}^3$)". I suspect the source of confusion here is not whether the vectors are linearly independent, but something (?) else. Does your teacher not consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ to be a [subspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace) of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Yes, he Did.. Actually I got it now. It is to say that all possible R^2 planes in R^3  can not be generated by those two vectors rather a particular one can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ span a sheet, which,  as in the case of all sheets, is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$.

But no two vectors can span *all* sheets in $\mathbb R^{\color{blue}3}$, as then we would have two vectors spanning a three dimensional space, which is impossible...